# Translate from VBA to VB.Net Workbook and FileDialog

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on translating the code below from VBA to VB.Net. I am about 90% of the way there but I am stuck on 3 issues.

First, In VBA I used the Application.GetOpenFilename to open a file dialog from within my code, I can't seem to get that done on VB.

Second, I am trying to export a sheet and copy the data onto a sheet on my workbook. I use the following line of code:

```
     With Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Open(strImportFile)
            .Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Workbooks(strSourceFile).Worksheets(sDestSheet).Range("A1")
            .Close(savechanges:=False)
```

Unfortunately, the middle line is not working the Workbooks gives me an error that it cannot be used as type.

And finally, I am trying to get the Application ScreenUpdating, but that also fails.  Here is the rest of my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Module adminModule

    Function GetImportFile(Index As Long) As String

        'This function is used in the import_Module to name all of the files
        'that will be imported to the template. The function is primarily used by
        'Sub import_OC_Data

        Select Case Index

            Case 1 : GetImportFile = "byemployee.csv"
            Case 2 : GetImportFile = "byposition.csv"
            Case 3 : GetImportFile = "statusreport.xls"
            Case 4 : GetImportFile = "bydepartment.csv"

        End Select

        Return ""

    End Function

    Function GetDestSheet(Index As Long) As String

        'This function is used in the import_Module to name all of the sheets
        'where the files will be imported to in template.The function is primarily used by
        'Sub import_OC_Data

        Select Case Index

            Case 1 : GetDestSheet = "byDepartment"
            Case 2 : GetDestSheet = "byPosition"
            Case 3 : GetDestSheet = "statusReport"
            Case 4 : GetDestSheet = "byDepartment"

        End Select

        Return ""

    End Function

    Sub importRawData()

        Dim xlWBPath As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path


        Dim n As Long
        Dim strSourceFile As String
        Dim strImportFile As String
        Dim sDestSheet As String


        Dim strTitle As String = "Verify Source File"
        Dim strPrompt As String = " source file does not exist." & vbNewLine & "Press OK to browse for the file or Cancel to quit"
        Dim strAlert As String = ("You have not selected a workbook." & vbNewLine & "Press Retry to select a workbook or Cancel to exit program")
        Dim strVmbProceedResults As String = ("Procedure Canceled. Your workbook will now close")
        Dim vmbContinue As MsgBoxResult
        Dim vmbProceed As MsgBoxResult



        strSourceFile = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Na

        For n = 1 To 4 Step 1
            strImportFile = xlWBPath & GetImportFile(n)
            sDestSheet = GetDestSheet(n)

            If Len(Dir(strImportFile)) > 0 Then
                With Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Open(strImportFile)
                    .Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Workbooks(strSourceFile).Worksheets(sDestSheet).Range("A1")
                    .Close(savechanges:=False)
                End With

            Else

                vmbProceed = MsgBox(strImportFile & strPrompt, vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, strTitle)
                If vmbProceed = vbCancel Then
                    vmbProceed = MsgBox(strVmbProceedResults, vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
                    Globals.ThisWorkbook.Close(saveChanges:=False)
                    Exit Sub

                Else

                    strImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.csv), *.xls; *.csv; *.xlsx; *.xlsm")
                    If strImportFile = "False" Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    vmbContinue = MsgBox(strAlert, vbRetryCancel + vbCritical, "No Workbook Selected")

                    If vmbContinue = vbCancel Then
                        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Close(saveChanges:=False)
                        Exit Sub

                    Else

                        strImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.csv), *.xls; *.csv; *.xlsx; *.xlsm")
                        Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Open(Filename:=strImportFile)

                        With Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Open(strImportFile)
                            .Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Workbooks(strSourceFile).Worksheets(sDestSheet).Range("A1")
                            .Close(saveChanges:=False)

                        End With

                    End If

                    On Error GoTo exit_

                    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                    Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Open(Filename:=strImportFile)
                    With Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Openn(strImportFile)
                        .Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Workbooks(strSourceFile).Worksheets(sDestSheet).Range("A1")
                        .Close(savechanges:=False)

                    End With
exit_:
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    If Err() Then MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error")
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: There are quite a few parts which need an improvement. You haven't converted the VBA into VB.NET properly, but just taken advantage from the VB.NET capabilities (can deal with quite a few things as VBA does). I recommend you to restart from scratch with a 100% VB.NET code; this link will be quite useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302094 Get a bit used to the VB.NET format (Excel.Application, Workbook(s) and then Worksheet(s) -> 3 objects to be declared/accessed for each new file you want to consider). Now quick answers to your questions (but not solutions for your real problem)...

Comment: OpenFileDialog is the VB.NET control to deal with dile dialogs. Your second problem derives from not considering the reality properly (1 Excel.Application + Workbook + Sheets for each file), once you will understand the exact reality, you would solve this pretty easily. Regarding "ScreenUpdating", again it is something which has no real utility now (the same than relying on the generic "Application"); if you want to see the spreadsheet and how the values are being modified by the code, you can do objApp.Visible = True (where objApp is the Excel.Application of the corresponding file).

Comment: @varocarbas, Thank you, I will take a look at the article and see how it helps.